# finding increasing sequences of numbres from several vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, search, vector, sequence, vectorization

Assume that we have three vectors say a, b and c including increasing real-valued numbers as follows:

```
a=[3 4 19 22];    
b=[1 10 15];
c=[3 5 11];
```

What is the most efficient way (**without using loops**) to find **increasing** sequence of numbers in such a problem in MATLAB?

For the above example the output should be like this:

```
[3 10 11]
[4 10 11]
```

Which both have their first element from a, their second one from b and their third one from c, so they have three increasing elements as it should be.
Note: The first number have to come from a, the second from b and the third from c.

Using loops is not a good choice for this problem because the vectors may have more length and the number of vectors would be increased in general cases, so the run time would take so long.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated…
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I am probably too stupid to see the relation here, but maybe you would be able to explain this more carefully for idiots like me? In particular the requirement for a number to be selected. For example, it seems as 5 would fulfil the requirements as well, why cannot c(2) be selected?).

Comment: And does the first number have to come from `a`, the second from `b` and the third from `c`?

Comment: If you don't want to use loops, you'll have to store every possible combination somewhere and then probably make a call to `issorted`. The problem is that the combination matrix will be as big as the product of the length of all the input vectors, possibly causing memory problems

Comment: Yes, You are right
the first number have to come from a, the second from b and the third from c

Comment: Sorry Patrik, it was my fault. I have edited that. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can do this without loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of approaching this problem, and one should always consider the time vs. space payoffs.

Approach 1 (Requires a lot of space (n^3 where n is the length of the arrays) but has no direct loops!):

```
[A,B,C] = meshgrid(a,b,c);
idxs = find((A<B)&(B<C));
[ib,ia,ic] = ind2sub(size(A),idxs);
answer = [a(1,ia);b(1,ib);c(1,ic)];
```

Approach 2 (Requires less space (n^2 where n is the length of the arrays), but does contain a loop, but it seems to be faster for big values of n. This approach is much faster if you only need to find how many solutions there are.):

```
ab = double(bsxfun(@lt,a',b));
bc = double(bsxfun(@lt,b',c));
abc = ab*bc;
numberOfAnswers = sum(abc(:));
[idx] = find(abc);
cumnum = [0;cumsum(abc(idx))];
[ia,ic] = ind2sub(size(abc),idx);
answer = zeros(3,numberOfAnswers);
for i = 1:numel(idx)
  answer(1,(cumnum(i)+1):cumnum(i+1)) = a(ia(i));
  answer(2,(cumnum(i)+1):cumnum(i+1)) = b((b>a(ia(i)))&(b<c(ic(i))));
  answer(3,(cumnum(i)+1):cumnum(i+1)) = c(ic(i));
end
```

**EDIT:** Both methods will give a `3`-by-`m`-matrix where `m` is the number of solutions, and the solutions will be the columns of the matrix.

Comment: I think you need to transpose your final matrices to make it match the expected output.

Comment: @kkuilla You are correct. I have elaborated my output format in a comment.

Comment: It's much better to transpose it in the end. Less confusion if someone just copies and paste the code..

Comment: Nice use of `meshgrid`!

Comment: What if we want to generalize this code for more than three vectors?

Comment: This is an example when an small error occurred:
a=[32 2725 3654 5017 5028 6109];
b=[36 1572 1852 3666 4236 6187 6238 6640];
c=[2261];

Comment: @Remy I tested it, and approach 2 still works fine. Approach 1 gives you problems because `c` only has one entry. Normally when you use a `x(ix)`-statement, where `x` is a vector and `ix` is a vector of integers between `1` and the number of elements in `x`, `x(ix)` will be a vector in the same direction as `x` (i.e. if `x` is a row vector, then `x(ix)` will be a row vector, and likewise for column vectors). But when `x` only contains one element, it is both a row and a column vector, so `x(ix)` takes its direction from the direction of `ix`. Solution: `answer = [a(ia');b(ib');c(ic')]`.

Comment: @JensBoldsen Yes, you explained the problem correctly, but this solution doesn't work for me when I tested it. Thanks again

Comment: @JensBoldsen This solution can be applied instead:  answer = [a(1,ia);b(1,ib);c(1,ic)];